# Traveling with exempt visa in UK

Tags: uk, international-travel

I am getting exempt visa for UK. I need to know which countries I can visit there without needing any other visa?

Comment: @GayotFow that sounds like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Why people have down voted the question, it's a valid one.

Comment: I for one have no idea what "I am getting exempt visa for UK" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "exempt visa" (besides being an oxymoron) is a type of visa that shows the holder is exempt from immigration control but does not have 'right of abode' in the UK.  It has no meaning outside of the UK.

> I am getting exempt visa for UK. I need to know which countries I can
>   visit there without needing any other visa?

You can visit England, Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland, and for limited periods, Ireland and the Channel Islands and the Isle of Man.

---

Regarding the UK and Schengen...

Schengen is a different regime and visas issued by the UK are not fungible in the Schengen zone (and vice versa). Your Schengen application may be elevated to bona fide status because of a UK visa (or it may not), but those considerations are pure conjecture.

Comment: Is there any issue in getting the schengen visa?

Comment: @CodeYogi answer updated